# How to mount EXT4 drives from another system

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, ext4, lvm

I had a testbed 13.04 server which had a boot volume partitioned into three, root, swap and Workspace as well as two other drives running in raid 1. The Workspace and raid volumes were setup using LVM and MDADM under Webmin and formatted with EXT4.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 onto the same system, deleting the root and swap partitions first. Now when I attempt to mount the volumes under Webmin it fails with the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntux64--vg-Workspace,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Looking at dmesg it shows the error:

```
EXT2-fs (dm-0) error couldn't mount because of supported optional features
```

The volume is formatted as EXT4 so not sure why it is defaulting to EXT2. If I do an `fdisk -l` the volumes show but it says that they don't have a valid partition table.

I can manually mount the volumes at the command line specifying EXT4 but how can I correct the partition table error which I think is causing Ubuntu to default to EXT2/3?

Comment: You aren't seeing a partition table error, you are seeing a "this isn't an ext2 filesystem" error because apparently you are trying to mount an ext4 filesystem as an ext2 one.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to unambiguously define a partition as ext4fs vs. ext2fs in the partition table, so there is no partition table error that can explain this problem. I recommend you look at your `/etc/fstab` file. There may be an entry in there that misidentifies the filesystem type; or if there's no `/etc/fstab` entry for the problem volume, you can create one that explicitly identifies it as ext4fs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - there is no entry in the fstab file. I can manually mount the volumes at the cli but wondering why I am seeing the no partition table error.

Comment: You have reported no partition table error. The error messages you've reported refer to filesystem type issues. Please re-read my answer; I refer to adding an `/etc/fstab` entry for the errant logical volume.